# Is it possible to put an if statement into the scripted expression of a driver?

Tags: python, drivers

If the y location of a certain object is greater than 0, I want to add a fixed amount to another object's driven channel. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A Python expression you can use is:

```
valueIfTrue if isConditionTrue else valueIfFalse
```

This is known as a `ternary conditional operator` see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/ternary-conditional-operator-in-python