# How do I add a conditional statment with a driver?

Tags: drivers

I want to add this expression in my driver panel but I dunno where to place a conditional equation. Emphasis on WHERE. When I place it different boxes I get an error.

var=0 if var > 1

For now I'm using floor as a makeshift conditional statement.

floor(sin(var*2)+.1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to put an if statement into the scripted expression of a driver?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2892/is-it-possible-to-put-an-if-statement-into-the-scripted-expression-of-a-driver)

Comment: @RichSedman Not duplicate, the duplicates talk about how to make a statement or if it can be done, I want to know where to put it in the drivers panel.

Comment: Ah. You just set it to Scripted Expression and put the text into the expression field.

Comment: @RichSedman  Doesn't work Type: Scripted Expression Expr: var=0 if var>1 ERROR: Invalid Python expression.

Comment: Try “0 if var < 1 else sin(var*2)”

Comment: @RichSedman It works but there is a syntax to this, you must include the "else" statement not just the "if" or it won't acknowledge as valid. That is why it never worked for me. So for what I want, it has to go like this: 0 if var>1 else var

Comment: Yes, the syntax is important. From your question it was specifically emphasising the *where* this is entered - and you mentioned ‘sin(var*2+0.1)’ and conditional statements so it seemed that you already knew *what* to enter - just not where. Glad you’ve got it working now.

Comment: @RichSedman I thought I was getting an error for putting a conditional statement in that box but I knew that you could put math in that same box  but not IF/THEN type statements so I believed that I had to put it somewhere else to add that type of statement.