# Is there any driver expression for elif statement?

Tags: python, drivers

Is there any way to add `if` `elif` and `else` in drivers?

Given the way we do if and else, here are two examples out of few other things i tried to get the statement right but unable to do so:

```
var-3.5 if (var<0) var+3.5 elif (var>0) else 1

var-3.5 if (var<0) elif var+3.5 (var>0) else 1
```

And also if there's any other way to add multiple if/else similarly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Nest the [ternary conditional operator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2894/15543)**

```
(var + 3.5) if var > 0 else (var - 3.5) if var < 0 else 1
```

or for more detailed scripts

```
import bpy

def x(var):
    if var > 0:
        return var + 3.5
    elif var < 0:
         return var - 3.5
    else:
         return 1

bpy.app.driver_namespace["x"] = x
```

And then use `x(var)` as your driver expression.

Comment: Nesting the ternary conditional operator worked! Thankyou! Also thanks for the detailed version!

Comment: Thanks.  One thing worth mentioning is the `use_self` option, which is the object being driven, passed as an argument, for example `x(self)` and `var = self.location.x` in the method instead of setting up a variable of the same in driver panel is worth looking into.

Comment: Ah! I had tried self driver between translate and rotate not via the script but via the panel, and the object started going crazy.. will try the same thing with the script you mentioned. This will be awesome! Thanks again mate!

Answer (score 2):

To use anything more than a simple python line in a driver you can define your own functions and add them to the [driver namespace](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/workflow_examples.html#driver-namespace).

```
import bpy

def myfunc(var, amt):
    if var < 0:
        return var - amt
    elif var > 0:
        return var + amt
    return 1

bpy.app.driver_namespace['mydrvr'] = myfunc
```

Then in the driver expression you put `mydrvr(var, 3.5)`

Comment: Thanks! As for now nesting the ternary conditional operator as said by batFINGER worked but will keep this in mind :)