# Question Using Drivers, Control the driver at specific frame to either turn off or minimize effect

Tags: drivers

I am using a driver in blender that controls a ShapeKey (ponytail moves up)
I am assigning that driver to act on the spine bone in the head. so if the head looks up, the ponytail wont clip into the clothes/body.

I works well except at some parts of my animation, where I would like to turn off the driver, or control it. (changing its strength)

unlike the fcurves and dope sheet, I cannot seem to work past frame 0 (the green cursor is moving around but does nothing) the white little driver cursor in the drivers section is stuck on frame 0, the orange blocks can move around but they do weird stuff to make the driver change strength.. but not at specific frame numbers.

I am lost.[image: Drivers Help]

You can see the drivers when zoomed out to insane numbers...
[image: Drivers1]
[image: Drivers2]

Comment: You can't animate a driver, it calculates the value instead of using the fcurve value. You could use `frame` in the driver expression, or [define your own function](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/109357/935) for more complex expressions. You could also drive the shapekey using  a bone location and animate the bone to control the shapekey.

Comment: What do you mean use frame in expression?
I actually created a 2nd shape key and tweaked that to correct what I needed.

Comment: In a driver expression you can use a variable called `frame` which is the current frame. So you can do `0.3 if frame == 5 else 0.8`