# How to make multiple objects rotate and retract with an equal offset around a point?

Tags: modeling, workflow, drivers

I'm trying to model something to be retractable and I can't figure out how to make the parenting system. The idea is that once the first shape hits a distance limit the second piece starts moving, then the 3rd, 4th etc.

Is that done with drivers? Constraints? A general idea would help me a lot already.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Drivers with IF conditions expression

As you mentioned, you could link the rotation of the pieces with a driver. In the expression you can use a ternary conditional operator (see for example: [Is it possible to put an if statement into the scripted expression of a driver?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2892/is-it-possible-to-put-an-if-statement-into-the-scripted-expression-of-a-driver)) to make the rotation occour only when one reach te other.

Here's an example using this statement:

```
var if var>0 else 0
```

Given that the 2nd bar has on Z rotation=0° and the first one on the bottom something like -30°... the rotatation will be equal to Z until the first bar reaches in its rotation a value higher than zero. From that point going on the second bar will pick a rotation equal to the one of the first (var).

[image]

[image]

For subsequential pieces, you should just add an angle offset in the expression. Here's some examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Final result of the rig:

[image]

Comment: This is amazing and beyond what I expected for an answer. Thank you so much Carlo, I'll use this technique in a bunch of stuff from now on. Hope you have an amazing week and thanks again. :')